# How do I repeat this and save the result for each section?

Tags: python

```
def main():
    section = 'A'
    while section:
        section = (input('What section are you inputing ticket numbers for? '))
        if section in ('a', 'A') :
            limit = 300
            cost = 20
            ticketSold = getTickets(section, limit)
            sectionACost = calcIncome(ticketSold, cost)
        elif section in ('b', 'B'):
            limit = 500
            cost = 15
            ticketSold = getTickets(section, limit)
            sectionBCost = calcIncome(ticketSold, cost)
        elif section in ('c', 'C'):
            limit = 200
            cost = 10
            ticketSold = getTickets(section, limit)
            sectionBCost = calcIncome(ticketSold, cost)
    displayTotals()



def getTickets(section, limit):
    ticketSold = int(input('How many tickets were sold? '))
    return int(ticketSold)
    if ticketsValid(ticketSold, limit):
         return ticketsValid

def ticketsValid(ticketSold, limit):
    if ticketSold <= limit:
        status = True
    else:
        status = False
    return status

def calcIncome(ticketSold, cost):
    sectionIncome = ticketSold * cost
    return sectionIncome

 def displayTotals():
     print('Section A generated {}'.format(sectionACost))
    print('Section B generated {}'.format(sectionBCost))
    print('Section C generated {}'.format(sectionCCost))
    totalRevenue = sectionACost + sectionBCost + sectionCCost
    print('The total revenue is {}'(totalRevenue))


main()
```

My problem is now that the loop doesn't exit to display the totals

Additional Problem Requirements:

• Create a main module as your program start module

• Use local named constants in the main module for seat costs and section seat limits that will be passed to the modules and functions described under the following points.

• Although there are three seating sections in the problem, a set of generic modules and functions will be created that are used for any given section based upon the passed parameters. The general logic for these function is described below:

o Include input function (getTickets) that takes section letter and seat limit for given section as parameters. The number of tickets for the given section is returned. This function should only return a valid number of tickets; the validation function, ticketsValid, should be called from this function.

o Include validation function (ticketsValid) that takes the tickets sold per section and seat limit per section as passed parameters. A Boolean indicating whether the passed tickets sold for the given section is in the valid range is returned. This validation function will be called from within the previously defined getTickets function.

o Include income calculation function (calcIncome) that takes tickets sold and seat cost as passed parameters and returns the income generated for the section.

• Be sure to use the currencyFormat

Comment: Surely you mean to indent the `if section = 'b'…calcIncome` parts as well?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I screw up the formatting on here a lot. Up until here it runs perfect, no syntax errors etc.

Comment: I believe I fixed the indentation the way you intended – let me know if not. (also isn't English funny? *intended* and *indented*)

Comment: `if section == 'a' or 'A':` will always evaluate to `True`.  You meant one of `if section == 'a' or section == 'A':`, `if section in ('a', 'A'):` or `if section.lower() == 'a':`

Comment: For this to work as nice as you want, you should make this a class.

Comment: Seth, I'm not sure what you mean. Are you referring to the ticketsValid function? That's supposed to validate the number of tickets that the user input to make sure it doesn't exceed the amount of tickets in that section. Did I do that wrong?

Mona, I don't believe we've covered "classes" yet, so it would probably be out of the realm of things I'm allowed to do

Comment: @mechabee open a terminal and type `if 'b' in 'A' or 'a': print('oops')`

Comment: Take a look at each `if` statement in your `main` function.  Each one is something like `if section == 'a' or 'A':`.  In python, a non-empty string is always `True`.  This statement is like `if (section == 'a') or True:` and if section is not 'a', it would be `if False or True:` which is *always* `True`.

Comment: I think, `if section in ['a', 'A']:` was better. `if section == 'a' or 'A'` is replica of `if (section == 'a') or 'A':` and, `'A'` was always `True`.

Comment: I see! So parentheses should solve that then (and in) Thanks! That's something I would have never caught! Any idea on the loops/storing to display a final total of all sections?

Comment: No, no.  Parentheses don't solve it.  Take a look at the three suggestions I gave initially.  You will see that you had to do more than just adding parentheses.

Comment: Yup, I edited my comment. sorry. Any idea on the loops/storing to display a final total of all sections?

Comment: @mechabee: The only thing you could do with parentheses is change it to `if section == ('a' or 'A')`. But `('a' or 'A')` is just `'a'` (try it in your interpreter to see). That's why it's still wrong.

Comment: If you just hit enter (= input empty string) when your program says "what section are you inputting ticket numbers for? " it should break the while loop and move on to the `displayTotals` function. However that function contains a bug: it should receive `sectionXCost` variables (X = A,B,C) as function arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in this code before I address your main concern:

```
def main():  
    section = (input('What section are you inputing ticket numbers for? '))
    if section == 'a' or 'A': # You mean if section in 'Aa':
        limit = 300
        cost = 20
    if section == 'b' or 'B': # You mean elif section in 'Bb':
        limit = 500
        cost = 15
    if section == 'c' or 'C': # You mean elif section in 'Cc':
        limit = 200
        cost = 10
    ticketSold = getTickets(section, limit)
    calcIncome(ticketSold, cost)

def getTickets(section, limit): # Doesn't actually use section.
    ticketSold = int(input('How many tickets were sold? '))
    return int(ticketSold) # Everything after this is dead code.
    if ticketsValid(ticketSold, limit): # Even if this did get called, 
        return ticketsValid # What should it return if the tickets aren't valid? 0?
```

---

Now that we have that out of the way, let's address the question asked:

> Display the generated income for each section as well as the theater total.

The way the code is currently written this is trivial, because you only call `main` once, and main only processes on section. The answer is always going to `0` for all but one section.

But let's see what happens if we assume you call `main` continuously until some condition is met:

```
def main():
    while section:
        section = (input('What section are you inputing ticket numbers for?'))
        if section in 'Aa':
            limit = 300
            cost = 20
    elif section in 'Bb':
        limit = 500
        cost = 15
    if section in 'Cc':
        limit = 200
        cost = 10
    ticketSold = getTickets(section, limit)
    calcIncome(ticketSold, cost)
```

Well, there are some fairly sophisticated solutions we might see, but based on this code I'm going to assume the simplest thing: one variable per section. We could use global names…

```
section_a_cost = 0
section_b_cost = 0
section_c_cost = 0
```

We'd need a function to display the final totals:

```
def displayTotals():
    '''display the totals'''
    print('Section A generated {}'.format(section_a_cost)
    print('Section B generated {}' …) # I leave the rest to you.
    # How do we generate the total for the theater?

def main():
    section = 'A' # whatever, just to get us started
    while section:
        section = input('What section are you inputing ticket numbers for? ')
        if section in 'Aa':
            limit = 300
            cost = 20
            ticketSold = getTickets(section, limit)
            section_a_cost += calcIncome(ticketSold, cost)
        elif section in 'Bb':
            limit = 500
            cost = 15
            ticketSold = getTickets(section, limit)
            section_b_cost += calcIncome(ticketSold, cost)
        elif …
            …
    displayTotals()
```

(Aside: In case it's not clear, my goal here isn't the best possible solution for a real-world problem – I'm making an assumption about where OP is in coursework and trying not to jump too far ahead by using sophisticated data structures or aggregators. I'm also trying not to give a full answer, but instead answering in the [vein of how to answer a homework question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812).)

Comment: I'm not a big fan of `if section in 'Aa':` because it would match the string `'Aa'` as well.  That is why I make it explicitly `if section in ('A', 'a'):`

Comment: @SethMMorton I might be on board with that IRL, but here, if someone types 'Aa' he/she most likely just meant section 'a' anyway.

Comment: That's probably true.  It depends on your programming style... I prefer to never assume.

Comment: @SethMMorton It's certainly true that there are better ways to handle processing that input, but I feel it's out of scope, so I took the easy way out.

Comment: Based on your "Aside" I now agree with you

Comment: Thanks! The only issue is that every function/module I have in the original code is part of the requirements. EDIT:: I inserted the additional requirements listed. I'm going to try calling a function in each elif and seeing if that works

Comment: @mechabee The other two functions you wrote are fine. Use them.

Comment: Sorry for having so many questions, I'm a hardware girl. You put    section = 'A' 

why? also, the while... while until what? Also, wouldn't displayTotal go under the main because the variables/whatever wouldnt be set yet?

Comment: @mechabee remember how everyone said any non-empty string is True? `while section` makes the loop continue until the user enters the empty string. You just need a nonempty `section` to enter the loop.

Comment: Ok, now my loop doesn't exit to display the totals. I posted my updated script